# This line of code finds the max element in an array, could someone please walk me through how this code accomplishes this using reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

this code finds the max element in an array using the reduce command.

```
function getMaxY(){
    return data.reduce((max, b) => Math.max(max, b.y), data[0].y);
}
```

Comment: ok what is your problem?

Comment: How `reduce` works, is explained pretty well [in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Might not be an exact duplicate, but the answers explain a bit more about how reduce works

Comment: `data[0].y` should be `0` to make it work in edge cases.